# Looking for suggestions to solve an integral exactly

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^{d}\rightarrow [0,1]$.
I would like to compute the following integral:
$$
\int\;\|\nabla f(\mathbf{w})\|^{2}\nabla f(\mathbf{w})\;d\mathbf{w}
$$
where 
$\|\nabla f(\mathbf{w})\|^{2}$ is the vector norm of the gradient of $f$ in $\mathbf{w}$.
Any idea?
Thank you!
Fabio

Comment: Since $\Vert \nabla f(w)\Vert_2^2$ is a nonnegative real number, you have $$\int\Vert\nabla f(w)\Vert_2^2\nabla f(w)dw=\Vert\nabla f(w)\Vert_2^2\int\nabla f(w)dw.$$

Comment: Thanks! but I do not understand how I can take out of the gradient  norm, being it a function of $w$.

Comment: I apologize, but perhaps I have misunderstood your notation: did you mean $$\| f(w)\|^2_2\triangleq\left( \int |f(w)|^2 dw \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\:?$$

Comment: @Fabio The norm does not depend on $w$, in fact the $w$ that was placed there is misleading. The norm itself is computed as an integral so it is really bad notation to use the same variable as in the outer integral.

Comment: @Daniele@Pierre, $\nabla f(w)\in \mathbb{R}^{d}$ and its norm is the norm of the gradient of the function at point $w$, so it depends on $w$. Am I correct?

Comment: @Fabio, if you are meaning the standard norm on $\Bbb R^n$, it is customary to write it as $$\|\boldsymbol x\|\triangleq\sqrt[2]{x_1^2+x_2^2+\ldots + x_n^2}\iff \|\boldsymbol x\|=x_1^2+x_2^2+\ldots + x_n^2.$$ The simbol $\| f \|_2$ where $f$ is a function whose domain is contained in $\Bbb R^n$, is something very different i.e. is the $L_2$ norm of $f$ $$\|f\|_2=\left(\int |f(x)|^2dx\right)^\frac{1}{2}\iff \|f\|_2^2=\int |f(x)|^2dx$$

Comment: @daniele, you are right! I did correct the question.